# How to call a QuickBooks API using PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks

I was able to integrate the OAuth2 authentication method and retrieve the Access Token Key.

But there's no clear documentation on how to send the parameters in a pure PHP CURL request.

Let's take the example below:

```
API: GET /v3/company/123146168204424/invoice/<invoiceId>?minorversion=38
```

How do I send the request in a PHP CURL and send the `ACCESS TOKEN, CLIENT ID, CLIENT SECRET`...

Comment: https://www.weichieprojects.com/blog/curl-api-calls-with-php/

Comment: @Mark thank you, but that's not what I want, I know how to use Curl, i just need to know the correct parameters in OAuth2 api

Comment: Can we get invoice pdf using curl ? Please add example here with how to create token use of key and secret. Because i not shown any example in document using curl.

Comment: @Heena here's the code I created to get the PDF and download it.
https://pastebin.com/NwDEFpv9
I used their PHP SDK to accomplish this task.